# React material UI compatibility with react 15.4.1 version

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a project having react version `^15.4.1`, which version of material UI can I use in the same project? I tried installing latest version of `@material-ui/core` and upgrading the react version, but its affecting so many other dependencies, is there any way to import `@material-ui/core` in the same react version?

Comment: material-ui does support most recent versions after 16.8.0, Please specify error that you're facing.  https://material-ui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/

Comment: To find a version of Material-UI that works with React 15, you would have to go all the way back to v0.20 (which would be a bad idea). Given the number of other packages whose latest versions no longer work with React 15, I think you would be best off to work through the issues with the various dependencies and upgrade to the latest React version.